# Applying certain functions on all the photos in flipview on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

I have flipview containing photo, descbox, detailBtn, hideBtn. I want when the photo on the tap, then descbox and hideBtn appear. whereas detailBtn not appear. And if the pictures on the tap again, then descbox and hideBtn not appear. while detailBtn appear.
Or if detailBtn in tap, then descbox and hideBtn appear. whereas detailBtn not appear. And if hideBtn on the tap, then the descbox and hideBtn not appear. while detailBtn appear. I want it applies to all photos (global) on the flipview. While the code below it applies one photo only.

XAML:

```
<FlipView x:Name="narrowFlipview" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Group.Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}"  Foreground="{x:Null}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot">
                        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection>
                                <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left"/>
                            </TransitionCollection>
                        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="myScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
                            <StackPanel Height="325" Width="558">
                                <Image x:Name="photo" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="320" Tapped="photo_Tapped" Margin="0,0,0.333,0" Tag="{Binding Tag, ElementName=narrowFlipview, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <Border x:Name="descbox" Background="#A52C2C2C" Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="{Binding IsDescriptionVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="0,-120,0,0">
                                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto" Height="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                        <StackPanel Width="538">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="desc" Text="{Binding Description}"  FontFamily="verdana" FontSize="17" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0,10" TextAlignment="Justify" Height="auto"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                                <Image x:Name="detailBtn" Margin="0,-40,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsDescriptionVisible,Converter={StaticResource boolToInverseVisibilityConverter}}" Source="images/media/arrow_up.png" Tapped="detailBtn_Tapped"/>
                                <Image x:Name="hideBtn" Margin="0,-285,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsDescriptionVisible,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" Source="images/media/arrow_down.png" Tapped="hideBtn_Tapped"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
```

Converter Class:

```
public class boolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public bool isInverseReq { get; set; }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            bool val = (bool)value;
            if (isInverseReq)
            {
                if (val)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                else
                    return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                if (val)
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

NatureDataSource class:

```
public class NatureDataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public NatureDataItem(String uniqueId, String title, String imagePath, String description, String content)
        {
            this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Description = description;
            this.ImagePath = imagePath;
            this.Content = content;
        }

        public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
        public string Content { get; private set; }

        //for the image tap to show description functionality
        private bool isDataVisible;
        public bool IsDataVisible
        {
            get { return isDataVisible; }
            set
            {
                isDataVisible = value;
                if (value)
                    IsDescriptionVisible = true;
                else
                    IsDescriptionVisible = false;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsDataVisible");
            }
        }

        //for hide and show the details pannel and hide and show content based on that
        private bool isDescriptionVisible;
        public bool IsDescriptionVisible
        {
            get { return isDescriptionVisible; }
            set { isDescriptionVisible = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsDescriptionVisible"); }
        }

        //raises the event to the view if any of these properties change
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Title;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic group data model.
    /// </summary>
    public class NatureDataGroup
    {
        public NatureDataGroup(String uniqueId, String title, String imagePath, String description)
        {
            this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Description = description;
            this.ImagePath = imagePath;
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<NatureDataItem>();
        }

        public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<NatureDataItem> Items { get; private set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Title;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a collection of groups and items with content read from a static json file.
    /// 
    /// NatureDataSource initializes with data read from a static json file included in the 
    /// project.  This provides Nature data at both design-time and run-time.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class NatureDataSource
    {
        private static NatureDataSource _NatureDataSource = new NatureDataSource();

        private ObservableCollection<NatureDataGroup> _groups = new ObservableCollection<NatureDataGroup>();
        public ObservableCollection<NatureDataGroup> Groups
        {
            get { return this._groups; }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<NatureDataGroup>> GetGroupsAsync()
        {
            await _NatureDataSource.GetNatureDataAsync();

            return _NatureDataSource.Groups;
        }

        public static async Task<NatureDataGroup> GetGroupAsync(string uniqueId)
        {
            await _NatureDataSource.GetNatureDataAsync();
            // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
            var matches = _NatureDataSource.Groups.Where((group) => group.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
            if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
            return null;
        }

        public static async Task<NatureDataItem> GetItemAsync(string uniqueId)
        {
            await _NatureDataSource.GetNatureDataAsync();
            // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
            var matches = _NatureDataSource.Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
            if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
            return null;
        }

        private async Task GetNatureDataAsync()
        {
            if (this._groups.Count != 0)
                return;

            Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/NatureData.json");

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
            string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

            foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
            {
                JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
                NatureDataGroup group = new NatureDataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                            groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                            groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                            groupObject["Description"].GetString());

                foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
                {
                    JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                    group.Items.Add(new NatureDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                       itemObject["Content"].GetString()));
                }
                this.Groups.Add(group);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<NatureDataGroup> GetGroupByItemAsync(NatureDataItem item)
        {
            await _NatureDataSource.GetNatureDataAsync();
            // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
            var matches = _NatureDataSource.Groups.Where(group => group.Items.Contains(item));
            if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

code:

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = await NatureDataSource.GetItemAsync((String)e.NavigationParameter);
            var group = await NatureDataSource.GetGroupByItemAsync(item);
            this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
            this.DefaultViewModel["Item"] = item;
        }
private void photo_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentItem = narrowFlipview.SelectedItem as NatureDataItem;
            currentItem.IsDataVisible = !currentItem.IsDataVisible;
        }

        private void detailBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentItem = narrowFlipview.SelectedItem as NatureDataItem;
            currentItem.IsDescriptionVisible = true;
        }

        private void hideBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentItem = narrowFlipview.SelectedItem as NatureDataItem;
            currentItem.IsDescriptionVisible = false;
        }
```

How do I apply it to all photos on the flipview?
Note: photos and descriptions of the data binding of NatureData.JSON

Comment: I would like if I tap a photo, then hideBtn and descbox appear, while detailBtn not appear. And if I tap the photo again, then hideBtn and descbox not appear, while detailBtn appear. Or if I tap detailBtn, then hideBtn and descbox appear, while detailBtn not appear. And if I tap hideaBtn, then hideBtn and descbox not appear, while detailBtn appear. That applies to photos, descbox, hideBtn, detailBtn on flipview to the next or previous index. While the code you provided, it only applies to index only tapped photo.

Comment: So you want if the user tapped on a photo the description and hide button appears and when he scrolls to the next picture then, the description and hide button is still visible? unless he taps on the image again. Did I understand correctly? What I meant was that instead of getting the `currentItem` each time you can make it into a property and bind the `FlipView.SelectedItem` property to this Property you've made via Two way Binding. And each time you want to perform any operation on the current selectedItem, you can do it with this property and the view would show

Comment: yes, it is what I want

Comment: To implement this, you need to create an observable collection in the code behind and bind the FlipView to it. And when the button's are pressed, you'll have to edit the IsDataVisible properties of each object in that collection. That's the easiest way it can be achieved.

Comment: can you give me the code?

Answer (score 0):

A Couple of things I've come across,

1. Try to avoid use of `Global Parameters` to hold value and transfer values, rather use `Local Parameters` and send them as while calling the method as Method Parameters.
2. Declare a single observable collection globally that is holding your entire data (your Groups in this case).
3. Use a Current Item property to bind your `FlipView.SelectedItem`in a `Two Way` fashion, this ways you'll have access to your CurrentSelectedItem and your data at all times which are the only two things that are necessary for any operation in your case.
4. Use a `ViewModel`class to hold all your properties and use DataContext of the Page to that `ViewModel` so that you won't need to do so from c# using `ObservableDirectory`. For More information on the MVVM pattern and ViewModels refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421874/basic-concepts-of-mvvm-what-should-a-viewmodel-do).
5. While Using LINQ, use the `FirstOrDefault` method to search for the element when you want/expect only a single element from a collection
6. In your case, you should use two observable collections

   1. for the Groups (as they can be many)
   2. for the group items (as they are many)

---

### The Changes is the code:

I've taken the liberty to change quite a bit of your code, removed the Global Objects, created Local Objects. Changed return Type of the methods to pass the local properties around. Below is my code based on the test project you had given during the last question:

### The XAML

Note: Set the `DataContext` of the `WaterfallDetail` page like this `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Title Panel -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding CurrentItem">
        <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Right"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        <!--<TextBlock x:Uid="Header" Text="application name" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>-->
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,15,50,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" FontSize="35" FontFamily="Myriad Pro Cond" FontWeight="Normal" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- 
        TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid 
              to show details for the current item
    -->
    <FlipView x:Name="narrowFlipview" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Group.Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  Foreground="{x:Null}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot">
                    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left"/>
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="myScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
                        <StackPanel Height="325" Width="558">
                            <Image x:Name="photo" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="320" Tapped="photo_Tapped" Margin="0,0,0.333,0" />
                            <Border x:Name="descbox" Background="#A52C2C2C" Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="{Binding IsDescriptionVisible,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="0,-120,0,0">
                                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto" Height="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                    <StackPanel Width="538">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="desc" Text="{Binding Description}"  FontFamily="verdana" FontSize="17" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0,10" TextAlignment="Justify" Height="auto"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                            <AppBarButton x:Name="detailBtn" Icon="Upload" Margin="0,-40,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsDescriptionVisible,Converter={StaticResource boolToInverseVisibilityConverter}}" Click="DetailsBtn_Click"/>
                            <AppBarButton x:Name="hideBtn" Icon="Download"  Margin="0,-285,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsDescriptionVisible,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" Click="HideBtn_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

### WaterfallDetail Page Code Behind

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface as discussed on your previous question. The changes are as below:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        //for c# versions below 6.0

        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        //if Using c# 6.0 with Visual Studio 2015
        //Comment the above and uncomment the below

        //PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private WaterfallDataGroup group;
    public WaterfallDataGroup Group
    {
        get { return group; }
        set { group = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Group"); }
    }


    private WaterfallDataItem currentItem;
    public WaterfallDataItem CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return currentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            currentItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }


    private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentItem = await WaterfallDataSource.GetItemAsync((String)e.NavigationParameter);
        Group = await WaterfallDataSource.GetGroupByItemAsync(CurrentItem);
    }

    private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Save the unique state of the page here.
    }

    private void photo_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentItem.IsDataVisible = !currentItem.IsDataVisible;
        Group.Items = Group.Items.Select(x =>
        {
            x.IsDataVisible = CurrentItem.IsDataVisible;
            return x;
        }).ToObservableCollection();
    }

    private void backBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.GoBack();
    }

    private void DetailsBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentItem.IsDescriptionVisible = true;
        Group.Items = Group.Items.Select(x =>
        {
            x.IsDescriptionVisible = CurrentItem.IsDescriptionVisible;
            return x;
        }).ToObservableCollection();
    }

    private void HideBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentItem.IsDescriptionVisible = false;
        Group.Items = Group.Items.Select(x =>
        {
            x.IsDescriptionVisible = CurrentItem.IsDescriptionVisible;
            return x;
        }).ToObservableCollection();
    }
```

Please Note: The `.ToObservableCollection()` is an extention method used to convert the `IEnumerable` to and `ObservableCollection` add the method in a different static class name `CollectionExtensions` in this case. You can read more about Extention Methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb383977.aspx).

### ExtentionMethod (.ToObservable())

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
    {
        var c = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        foreach (var e in coll)
            c.Add(e);
        return c;
    }
}
```

### The WaterfallDataGroup class

I've changed the Items property to have a `public setter` instead of a `private` one to be able to edit the `properties of the Items` on `Button Tap event`.

```
public class WaterfallDataGroup
{
    public WaterfallDataGroup(String uniqueId, String title, String imagePath, String description)
    {
        this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Description = description;
        this.ImagePath = imagePath;
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<WaterfallDataItem>();
    }

    public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<WaterfallDataItem> Items { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

### The Waterfall DataSource Class

```
 public sealed class WaterfallDataSource
{
    private static WaterfallDataSource _WaterfallDataSource = new WaterfallDataSource();

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<WaterfallDataGroup>> GetGroupsAsync()
    {
        var groups = await _WaterfallDataSource.GetWaterfallDataAsync();

        return groups;
    }

    public static async Task<WaterfallDataGroup> GetGroupAsync(string uniqueId)
    {
        var groups = await _WaterfallDataSource.GetWaterfallDataAsync();
        var matches = groups.Where((group) => group.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }

    public static async Task<WaterfallDataItem> GetItemAsync(string uniqueId)
    {
        var groups = await _WaterfallDataSource.GetWaterfallDataAsync();
        var matches = groups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }

    private async Task<ObservableCollection<WaterfallDataGroup>> GetWaterfallDataAsync()
    {
        ObservableCollection<WaterfallDataGroup> Groups = new ObservableCollection<WaterfallDataGroup>();
        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/WaterfallData.json");

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

        foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
        {
            JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
            WaterfallDataGroup group = new WaterfallDataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Description"].GetString());

            foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
            {
                JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                group.Items.Add(new WaterfallDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Content"].GetString()));
            }
            Groups.Add(group);
        }
        return Groups;
    }

    public static async Task<WaterfallDataGroup> GetGroupByItemAsync(WaterfallDataItem item)
    {
        var groups = await _WaterfallDataSource.GetWaterfallDataAsync();
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var match = group.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId == item.UniqueId);
            if (match != null)
                return group;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i got error message: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDUzdpNWFmTHh2RFU/view?usp=sharing  here is my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDX3JqUkZST3FKN1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: okay, so 1. in XAML you can remove any converter declations with "doNothingConverter" I used this to check if the data binding was working. So Remove ,Converter={StaticResource doNothingConverter} where ever you find it. 2. Your Items ObservableCollection in Groups has a private setter, Make that public and it'll start working like a charm. I've edited the answer for the same. Please let me know if there are any issues. If it solves your question, kindly mark my answer for future referances

Comment: i have changed it, but still error message: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDblVEX1A5cGlDWDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As from the above comment: Your Items ObservableCollection in Groups has a private setter, Make that public and it'll start working like a charm. I've edited the answer for the same. Please refer to the  `WaterfallDataGroup` class that I've added in the answer

Comment: Sorry, I missed to review replace ObservableCollection in the Group. There's no error message, but when the image is selected on the mainpage, flipview be empty and only a black screen on page WatefallDetail

Comment: This might be because of the DataContext of the WaterfallDetail Page.  Set it to `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` And remove the dataContext of the LayoutRoot.

Comment: i have set DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" And remove the dataContext of the LayoutRoot. But when the image is selected on the mainpage, flipview be empty and only a black screen on page WatefallDetail

Comment: I would like to point out I had added the changes to your WaterfallDetails Code behind, not the entire class. So you might have accidently replaced the entire class instead of modifying. You might have removed the `NavigationHelper registration` code portion. [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsbwVCO9nR4ogrk5YWdigi9xWy2QcA) is the link to the solution I made. Please let me know if the issue persists

Comment: I had a problem, ie the selected image on the MainPage is not the same as the image displayed on WaterfallDetail Page. How to handle it? Note: the image displayed on the WaterfalDetail page always the first image (not the same as the selected image on the MainPage)

Comment: Well yes that's an active bug in the control. I myself tested the entire solution for an hour just to realize that, there is an active bug on it. Read more about it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ace31cd7-2247-45c0-9a00-07457beac207/starting-a-flipview-with-a-specific-selected-item?forum=winappswithcsharp). Kindly mark my answer as correct as it solves your question. For the FlipView SelectedItem, you can either start a new Question Thread or do some research yourself.