# View or View Model?

Tags: mvvm

Where data binding/binder functionality should be implemented? It should be in **view** or **view model**?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should do in the view is:

1. Initiate/Layout/Present UI components.
2. Bind UI components with the ViewModel.

The viewmodel is for logic, they are objects that model a GUI application, this means they provide data and functionality to be used by views. They are what define the structure and behavior of the actual application you are building.

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421874/basic-concepts-of-mvvm-what-should-a-viewmodel-do). There is some really useful information about what a view should do and what a viewmodel should do.